# Dreamweaver/MyBB/MySQl Database?

Tags: mysql, database, ftp, dreamweaver, mybb

I have [MyBB](http://www.mybb.com/) installed on my server and apparently the template sets are stored via MySQL database instead of downloaded to the remote server.  I would like to set up a path in Dreamweaver so I can directly edit template sets without having to go into the acp in MyBB.  Otherwise, there's really no way to test locally unless I set up a database on my machine and it wouldn't make sense having two databases with the same entries.  Has anyone managed to set up an ftp path through Dreamweaver that will link to a MySQL database, or is this not possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question is better at home in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone managed to set up an ftp path through Dreamweaver that will
>   link to a MySQL database, or is this not possible?

Not possible.  Dreamweaver will let you create a connection to a MySQL database to query it but you cannot affect the database structure from within Dreamweaver's interface.